# Create Serialize JSON List Type object from c# class

Tags: c#, json

Dear All I am using C# Class and make the json object but how it call it.
and show the json object I am show the code please help me.

Here I am create a class

```
public class Contacts
{
    public List<PhoneMobile> phoneMobiles { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneLandline> phoneLandlines { get; set; }
    public List<Email> emails { get; set; }
}
public class PhoneMobile
{
    public string phoneMobile { get; set; }
}
```

Here i am use the class like this

```
contacts = new Contacts
    {
        phoneMobiles = new List<PhoneMobile>
        {

        },
        phoneLandlines = new List<PhoneLandline>(),
        emails = new List<Email>(),
    }
```

I want SerializeObject Like This objects give how to put a value and make it.

```
"contacts": {
      "phoneMobiles": [
        {
          "phoneMobile": "8103267511"
        }
      ],
      "phoneLandlines": [
        {
          "phoneLandLineNumber": "8103267511"
        }
      ],
      "emails": [
        {
          "email": "testing@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    "contactPerson": [
      {
        "personName": "TEST KARKHANA",
        "owner": "null",
        "email": "sanjeet.kumar@mponline.gov.in",
        "phone": "8602865989"
      }
    ],
```

How To Make It Please Help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm sorry but your question is not clear... **where** do you want to "show it"?

Comment: I want make a json object like this using c# classes "contacts": {
      "phoneMobiles": [
        {
          "phoneMobile": "8103267511"
        }
      ],
      "phoneLandlines": [
        {
          "phoneLandLineNumber": "8103267511"
        }
      ],
      "emails": [
        {
          "email": "testing@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    "contactPerson": [
      {
        "personName": "TEST KARKHANA",
        "owner": "null",
        "email": "sanjeet.kumar@mponline.gov.in",
        "phone": "8602865989"
      }
    ],

Comment: What is `contactPerson` class?

Comment: Have a look at [`Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.serialize?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @freefaller No, please don't recommend a library that nobody uses any more. The de facto standard is Newtonsoft JSON.Net

Comment: @DavidG, it's a library that is there, works, and doesn't require a external library to installed and referenced.  Not sure I see the problem

Comment: @freefaller It has it's own problems that won't get fixed, it doesn't exist in .NET Core, MVC doesn't use it, it's not open source, very few people explicitly use it these days. Shall I go on? :)

Comment: [link](http://json2csharp.com/) use this for creating model in c# based on your json, it's helpfull and saves time !! @RomanMarusyk got your answer allready

Comment: @DavidG - I've now had a chance to play with Newtonsoft JSON.Net.  I have one complaint... why didn't you tell me about it earlier?! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/) library, you can download it from Nuget.
Try this

```
var contactCollection = new Contacts
{
    phoneMobiles = new List<PhoneMobile>
    {
        new PhoneMobile { phoneMobile = "8103267511" }
    },
    phoneLandlines = new List<PhoneLandline>()
    {
        new PhoneLandline { phoneLandLineNumber = "8103267511" }
    },
    emails = new List<Email>()
    {
        new Email { email = "testing@gmail.com" }
    }
};

var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contacts);
```

It will serialize object to json except `contactPerson` section

If you need serialize object with root name `contacts` then try

```
var collectionWrapper = new {
    contacts = contactCollection
};

var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collectionWrapper);
```

then the result will be like:

```
{"contacts":{"phoneMobiles":[{"phoneMobile":"8103267511"}], "phoneLandlines":[{"phoneLandLineNumber":"8103267511"}], "emails":[{"email":"testing@gmail.com"}]}}
```